# Is it possible to include information about a neatline in a GeoTIFF?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

Is it possible to include information about a neatline in a GeoTIFF?  If so, how?  What software will produce them?

Comment: What format is your neatine? vector such as shapefile, postgis, etc or coordinates as kml. Is your neatline in the same coordinate system you want your geotiff cast? More details would help.

Comment: Sorry, my question was poorly worded.  I'm wondering if there there is a way to include information about a neatline in a GeoTIFF, similar to neatlines in Geospatial PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you will get desirable results with GDALs [gdaltindex](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html):

`gdaltindex output.shp input.tif`

For batch processing:

`gdaltindex output.shp folder/*.tif`

[image]

*Red line is the output neatline.*

The corner coordinates can also be returned using GDALs [gdalinfo](http://gdal.org/gdalinfo.html):

`gdalinfo folder/input.tif`

This will generate a bunch of information and among them will be the four corner coordinates which when connected would be the neatline.

Comment: I think gdalindex creates a shapefile from multiple images. Isn't this the opposite of what Josh wants?

Comment: I must of been confused then; thought it meant to **generate** a neatline _from_ a geotiff.

Comment: Sorry guys, my question wasn't worded very well.  I revised it.

Answer (score 0):

Using ArcMap, you can add x,y coordinate text to your View, then export the view to a Geotiff. What neatline info do you want to add? The corner coordinate values?

Answer (score 0):

In Autodesk software (AutoCAD Map 3d) any inserted image file has a printable outline (neatline).
You can turn off edge or image or both.
This is not the same in arcmap.